# How to output thumbnail twice in a WordPress loop

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

ok I have a portfolio page. Every portfolio item has thumbnail attached. what I want is to print out the first thumbnail from the first post twice. One at the beginning & other at the ending. like: image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4 & then image_1 again.

my code is:

```
<div class="main-interior portfolio" id="portfolio-big-pics" style="display: block;">
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'order' => 'dsc');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php $extraFirstClass = $loop->current_post == '0' ? ' main-image-porfolio-main' : ''; ?>

<?php 
$attributes = array(
    "class" => "main-image portfolio " . $extraFirstClass,
    "id" => "photo_{$post->ID}",
);
the_post_thumbnail("portfolio_thumb", $attributes);
?>

<?php endwhile; ?> 

<?php rewind_posts(); ?> 


    <div class="portfolio-box">
        <h5>Portfolio</h5>
        <ul class="item-list" id="portfolio-list">
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>              
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously answered by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628928/how-to-make-this-swap-image-code-working-in-wordpress/27629908#27629908), I would use PHP `for`. However, if for some reason you don't want that, I don't think you would need to resort to two loops for this. You can do the following:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'order' => 'dsc');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$first = $loop->posts[0];
$attributes = array(
    "class" => "main-image portfolio",
    "id" => "photo_{$loop->posts[$i]->ID}",
);

<div class="main-interior portfolio" id="portfolio-big-pics" style="display: block;">
    for( $i = 0; $i < count($loop->posts); $i++ ) {
        $attrs = $attributes;
        $attrs["class"] .= $i === 0 ? ' main-image-portfolio-main' : '';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $loop->posts[$i]->ID, "portfolio_thumb", $attrs );
    }
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $first->ID, "portfolio_thumb", $attrs );
    ?>

    <div class="portfolio-box">
        <h5>Portfolio</h5>
        <ul class="item-list" id="portfolio-list">

            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>            
            </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($first->ID);?>" rel="<?php echo $first->ID; ?>"><?php echo $first->post_title;?></a>
            </li>  
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the thumbnails should be outside of the "portfolio-box" div!

Comment: but I get some idea from your code..let me try, I ll let you know if I face any problem! thank you so much for your help!

Comment: yes I've solved my problem using a portion of your code. all I need was, just this two line: '$first = $loop->posts[0];
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $first->ID );?>'

thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your latest comments.

Answer (score -1):

here is the code, edit it according to your needs:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var imagesrc = $(".example post's image class").attr("src");
   $(".the container or post after which you want to put your image").appendTo("<img src='"+imgsrc+"' alt='image' />");
});
```